# How to add Window: beforeunload event to antd form

Tags: reactjs, antd, onbeforeunload, unload

Hi How can we add Window: beforeunload event to an antd form? For a single field, we can implement as below https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brattain-uufyg?file=/src/App.js:452-558

Comment: You can explain what you want to do ? (the goal)

Comment: Like I have an antd form. Now When a user changes anything in the form field wants to leave the page or tries to navigate other screens I want to show **Changes that you made may not be saved**. message. For all screens of the project, I want to add this feature. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use react router prompt. Here docs https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt

Comment: Can't I achieve this using Window: beforeunload event? Something like in the sandbox code?

Comment: Check my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `onFieldsChange` to understand when block the navigation:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

const { Item } = Form;

const App = () => {
  const [cannotLeave, setCannotLeave] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!cannotLeave) {
        return;
      }
      e.returnValue = true;
    };

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
  }, [cannotLeave]);

  const handleFieldsChange = () => setCannotLeave(true);

  return (
    <Form onFieldsChange={handleFieldsChange}>
      <Item name="test">
        <Input placeholder="Test " />
      </Item>
      <Item name="test">
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Live example:

[image: Edit colSpan and rowSpan - antd@4.18.5 (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Antd form instance has a `getFieldsValue` method (https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance).

You can get all values by calling `form.getFieldsValue(true)` and check if any field is filled.